# Can I automatically create a net class from this Blanket + Parameter? [ALTIUM]

Tags: altium

I added this blanket + parameter to my schematic, and now I want to create a net class from all of the nets that lay within the boundaries of the blanket.

Do I have to manually add all of the nets, or is there an easier way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-click on the parameter set object (labeled "HV" in your image) to open its properties dialog. In the right-hand panel click the "Add..." button and choose "Net Class". Then you can give the net class a name. This creates a net class for all nets inside the blanket.

[image]